# VtChart changes not saving in MS VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm working on some legacy code. I have a user control with a VtChart (VCI First Impression Library) in it and I'm trying to make changes to it, namely, adding another series to the control. However, every time I make changes to the control, close the form editor, then reopen it, the changes are gone.

I can't find any documentation on this control, so thought I'd ask the community, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Found my answer. Since VtChart is connected to a grid (F1Book), the SsLinkRange needs to correspond to the number of columns needed in the chart. For example, if you want 3 columns, SsLinkRange should be A1:C10, where A and C is the column range. If the SsLink properties don't match it won't save the settings.

This is an very obscure problem, but I'll post this answer anyways for archiving.